# Can't serialize form with jQuery (Django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a template

```
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_question' %}" role="form" id="question-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for answer in answers %}
      <div class="radio"><label name="answers-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="answers-radio"
               value ="{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.text }}
      </label></div>
    {% endfor %}
  </form>
```

(actually, it is part of template, but the rest is a things like `block`, `extends`, etc)

I try to serialize this form to send with AJAX request, but this code

```
$("#question-form").serialize()
```

don't work properly, it only returns

> csrfmiddlewaretoken=yYa3KW1pFWCAquX3FUsbMOHTfXE2z8g3

Form renders correct, i see all radio elements and other elements.

Comment: When are you serializing the form data?

Comment: in `<script>` in same page

Comment: Right, but are you waiting until the form is submitted to serialize the form? Or are you serializing it on page load?

Comment: after load. even if serialize it in browser's console, it show only csrfmiddlewaretoken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid error: i didn't select any radio element, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use

```
$("#question-form").serializeArray();
```

Here is a solution you could use or look at for ideas.  Hope this helps!

https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/bynaK/

Answer (score 1):

If you serialize the form on page load, you're only serializing the **initial data** (which is why you're only getting the `csrf_token` value). Instead, you want to serialize all of the fields, which won't have values until the fields have been filled out by the user, and `submit` is fired.

You'll have to adjust your form slightly to not POST immediately (you could remove the action Url if you're planning to use ajax and put that url in your ajax method). But something like this should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#question-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $('#question-form').serialize();
    });
})
```